# Browser automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am developing an application that will automate some tasks for me. The application needs to download an excel file, do some manipulations and write some data to the DB.

I have the excel automation and db writing code done, but I'm having some trouble with the browser automation.
What would be the best way to do the browser automation? What it needs to do is:

1. Go to a url
2. Set some dropdownlists
3. Click a button
4. save the excel file in the right place.

I have never done browser automation. What would be the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version, Visual Studio 2010 can do this, via the Test tools.  (mentioned in case you have a version with the feature but are unaware of it.)

I believe you need either the Test edition or the Ultimate edition for these features.

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison

Comment: I ended up using Coded UI, which is a feature of the testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser automation tool, such as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [WATIR](http://watir.com/).

These let you script most aspects of browser work (definitely going to a URL, setting form elements and clicking).

Answer (score 1):

If you need full automation, please pick http://watin.org/ for example. For what you write, however, the `WebRequest` should be enough, you'd only have to sniff requests with any http debugger (like Fiddler) and be able to replay them with web requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Selenium as well.  I use version 2 (WebDriver) extensively for this type of automation.  The only problem I see is that the Save File dialog is not something easily driven by Selenium.  There are a couple of workarounds out there though.  Does the clicking of the button open a dialog for download or is the button just a link to the url containing the download?

Answer (score 0):

Why, What and How of Software Test Automation ?

[very nice article see here](https://www.facebook.com/WebDriver/posts/204378022996783)